# setting value of parameter for query using sql in microsoft access

Tags: ms-access, prepared-statement

I have a query in access as follow:

```
select id, sum(amount) as totamt from expense group by id having year=[Year];
```

When I run this I get a prompt for year, I type say 2015 then click enter and the data appears for 2015.

Is it possible to create a new query (say exp2015) that set the year parameter to 2015 before calling the original query so that it would return data for 2015 without prompting the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's impossible. Each query instance has own independent set of parameters in memory. Try to redesign base query - use form field or function instead of parameter. You can also set parameter value using VBA.